# Всплывающее окно

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php, css

Нужно сделать окошко, которое просит человека зарегистрироваться на сайте, только в таком виде:

[image]

Смотрю в сторону jQuery Bootstrap Alerts, но пока не пойму, как это окно сделать вверху страницы и как сделать, чтобы оно появилось не сразу, а например, при прокрутке страницы вниз?

Answer (score 1):

Если я понимаю о чем речь, то скорей всего тебе нужно просто jQuery. Стороние библиотеки тебе не нужны.
Сверстай такое окошко, и по определенному условию (событию), выводи его.